# Query regarding ethernet header

Tags: ethernet, layer2

I have a query regarding ethernet header.

Some representation of ethernet header have Type Field and some tell it as Length field.
Which is the right one here ?

Comment: Both, depending on the ethernet version.

Comment: It does solve my query, however I have another query pertaining to that.
Is 802.3 the latest or Ethernet 2.
Also what's ethernet 2 called ?